# Every day reset a field to "0"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need that every day at 00:00am, reset a `studied_today` field to `0`.

original code:
models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings

class Studied(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    studied_today = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.collection.title
```

I try it:

```
$ pip install schedule
```

after, I change the original code:

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings

import schedule

class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    studied_today = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.collection.title

    def job():
        studied_today = 0

    schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(job)
```

What did I do wrong and how can I do this? Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you know it is wrong?  DId you get an error? Are you getting an unexpected result?

Comment: It will not change by itself it is IntegerField you are doing some changes in this field that is why it is changing. Can you please show where are you using this field?

Comment: @user1558604 nothing happened. The value has not changed.

Comment: @NVS thanks for the answer. I only need to put a counter in field that every day, at 00:00am it reset to "0". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

according to doc https://pypi.org/project/schedule/ , you need keep schedule.run_pending() run on every second, I think the better solution is set up a simple crontab on your server and trigger on middle night.